# Can I use the PhotoChooserTask to select an image saved in own project in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have 20 images in "/Images" folder in my WP7 project. So the question: Can I use the PhotoChooserTask to select an image from the folder and display it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no

Comment: You can reference project assets with a relative Uri.  You will have to decide what you want your UI to look like, and if it is your goal to mimic the PhotoChooser UI.  

Alternatively, your app could copy your assets from your app package to a folder in the user's documents library.  You just need to add the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB capability in your WMAppManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

PhotoChooserTask gives an access to camera or images stored on device. If you want to show photos from folder in project show them in LisBox, but I would suggest to user WrapPanel so you can view them in the same way as it is in Pictures Hub.

Comment: Thanks dargod! I thought too!